# C++ - Store part of string in another string

Tags: c++, string

The problem is that in my code (which there is a loop getting alphabets of a string) it can not save the current string input into another variable:

Here is the code:

```
if(isalpha(Str[i])){

        while (isalpha(Str[i])){
            i++;
        }
        Str.erase( 0, i);
        return 0;
    }
```

I want to have another string (like *temp* ) to save each alphabet into the while loop. something like this:

```
if(isalpha(Str[i])){
        string temp;
        while (isalpha(Str[i])){
            temp[i]=Str[i];
            i++;
        }
        Str.erase( 0, i);
        return 0;
    }
```

can anyone help that what is the problem here?

Comment: Your code sample is way off from a [MCVE]. Improve your question please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you declare `temp` as `0`  length string, using `temp[i]` would be undefined behavior.

You may solve this problem by using

```
temp.push_back(Str[i]);
```

instead of

```
temp[i]=Str[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a **position** and **count** to `std::string::erase`. You can use the same parameters to construct another string with the characters that are about to be erased.

```
while (isalpha(Str[i])) {
    i++;
}
string temp(Str, 0, i);
Str.erase(0, i);
```